# Regex Query get a group of string

Tags: regex, powershell

I just started learning regex on Powershell and I'm trying to resolve the problem below. I have this string `$user_access` and I want to get the list of users who are part of a group. See my example below.

Here's the `$user_access` content

```
$user_access = "
@group1
user1 = read
user2 = readwrite
user3 = read

@group2
user2 = read
user4 = readwrite
user5 = readwrite
  
@group3
user1 = readwrite
user4 = read
user6 = readwrite
"
```

I tried to use the pattern below.

```
$groupSelected = "group2"
$Result = $user_access.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | Select-String -Pattern "^\@$groupSelected"
```

but here's the only result I'm getting

```
@group2
```

Here's the result I want to get

```
@group2
user2 = read
user4 = readwrite
user5 = readwrite
```

I hope you guys can help. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Don't split lines, and use regex `@group2[^@]+`. You can check regexes [here](https://regex101.com/r/DpfrsD/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing *individual lines* to [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), which makes the latter report only those lines that match, i.e. you cannot match *blocks* of lines that way.

You can use the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to extract a block of lines:

```bash
$groupSelected = [regex]::Escape('group2')
$user_access -replace "(?sm)^.*^(@$groupSelected\r?\n.+?)\s*(?:\z|^@.+)$", '$1'
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/xsbIjl/3).

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Select-String` but with a little bit more complex regex and without splitting your input first:

```bash
$user_access | Select-String -Pattern "@$groupSelected[^@]+(?=\n|$)" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @markalex! I'll review and test your pattern.